# How to write a regular expression

Tags: c#

I need to write a regular expression that will be correct for telephone number with some rules:

```
1) max length 13 symbols
2) it should start from '+'
3) it should contain sonly numbers [0-9]
```

So, for example, it should be like this:

```
+447289347598342745
```

Comment: Your example's length is 18. (19 if you count the +)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^\+\d{1,13}$");
```

- [`^\+`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) → the string must start with  `+`. Note that `+` must be [escaped](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) because it has special meaning otherwise.
- [`\d`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand) → equivalent to the character class `[0-9]`
- [`{1,13}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) → there must be at least one and no more than 13 occurences of the digit characters

---

> In .NET, you should either use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, or else you should specify `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`. Otherwise, the regex will match a string like `+୧٢३੪૫` (which contains Unicode digits 1-5 in various scripts). – [Michael Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852734/how-to-write-a-regular-expression/9852752#comment12558992_9852752)

So either use:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^\+[0-9]{1,13}$");
// or
Regex re = new Regex(@"^\+\d{1,13}$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

Comment: That said, you probably want a minimum number of digits `>1` as well.

Comment: In .NET, you should either use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, or else you should specify `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`. Otherwise, the regex will match a string like `+୧٢३੪૫` (which contains Unicode digits 1-5 in various scripts).